# Domain Account Permission Issues

Tags: windows-7, uac, imaging

After creating a custom Windows 7 image I have an issue with once I join the domain. For example, a new hire hasn't got access to change the time and use `cmd`, probably more things but I haven't checked everything.

**How do I prevent this error message from occurring?**

> User Account Control:  Do you want to allow the following program to make changes to your computer?
>   To continue to type an administrator password then click yes.

And even if I disable UAC it still says

> Unable to continue.
>   You do not have permission to perform this task.  Please contact your computer administrator for help.

The account could be created as a standard account. But usually, if I just join the domain and enter the credentials there are no issues. But a way around this is joining the domain and then adding a user in users and setting that as administrator.